# Collabnet SVN Log files, are there any?

Tags: svn, collabnet

My svn server is acting funky.  We're using Collabnet svn binary on a Windows machine.

Does anyone know if the server has log files I can examine to find out what locks up my server (large commits hang)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using mod_dav_svn, the SVN log messages will be within Apache logs. If you're running svnserve prior 1.6, quoth a [mailing list posting](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-07/0444.shtml):

> svnserve does not have any logging capability.

since version 1.6 svnserve can write to a [log file](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#svnserve-logging)

Answer (score 3):

$ svnserve --version
svnserve, version 1.6.12 (r955767)

Start your daemon using --log-file=/var/log/svnserve.log
(for example)

It doesn't log authentication, but you can know what repo is accessed and what commands were issued by your users.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to Apache `subversion.conf`:

```
CustomLog logs/svn_logfile "%t %u@%h %>s repo:%{SVN-REPOS-NAME}e %{SVN-ACTION}e (%B Bytes in %T Sec)" env=SVN-ACTION
```

Example output:

```
[07/Apr/2015:09:54:40 -0500] user@127.0.0.1 200 repo:java commit r24 (758 Bytes in 2 Sec)
```